# ED25519 for Putty 0.67 login failed

Tags: putty, ed25519

I'm not sure if Putty 0.67 supports ED25519, in my case, the key work successfully under command line mod (DOS or BASH), but it dosen't work for Putty.

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current stable releases of putty (0.67) does not support elliptic curves. However, the nightly snapshot does.